# Busqueda por date en un datetime SQL EF C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL (lo que interesa aqui es el la fecha):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual tiene esta info de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo `fecha` se guarda el dia y la hora, si yo trato por ejemplo dentro de SQL, hacer un `WHERE fecha='05-04-2020'`, simplemente no me muestra nada, para poder visualizar el query con la fecha debo hacer algo asi:

```
SELECT*FROM tabla WHERE
year(fecha) = '2020'
and month(fecha) = '04'
and day(fecha)= '05' ;
```

Estoy trabajando usando EF, para poder hacer esta busqueda, estoy haciendo algo asi:

```
//TRAE LA INFO DE LOS DATOS POR FECHA
        public List<Cortes_Rollos> GetDataBolsasByDate(int fecha, int mes, int year)
        {
            try
            {
                var lista = new List<Cortes_Rollos>();

                using (var ctx=new ModelContext())
                {
                    lista = ctx.Cortes_Rollos.Where(x => x.parte_cortada.Contains("Filtros")
                                                    && x.fecha.Day == fecha
                                                    && x.fecha.Month == mes
                                                    && x.fecha.Year == year).ToList();
                    return lista;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Según yo, este código (no se si estoy mal), necesito buscar todo lo que en la columna `parte_cortada` tenga la palabra parecida (`LIKE`) a "Filtros", por eso uso `Contains`, despues  la fecha le paso cada parametro para tratar de recrear la consulta anterior, pero resulta que es vacia la lista. Mis preguntas:

1. ¿Que hago mal?
2. ¿Cual es la forma correcta de representar el query
       anterior en EF?

Gracias.

Comment: seguramente en tu sql deberias usar la fecha en ingles mm/dd/aaaa o aaaa/mm/dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando armas el `sql` para indicar una fecha debes hacerlo en formato `ISO` o sea `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
WHERE fecha= '2020-04-05'
```

Ahora bien para `linq` puedes usar un `datetime` de c# y lo igualas en el where

```
 DateTime fecha = new DateTime(year, mes, dia);

 lista = ctx.Cortes_Rollos.Where(x => x.parte_cortada.Contains("Filtros")
                                     x.fecha == fecha).ToList();
```

Nota: no se porque al parametro que representa el dia lo llamaste fecha

Comment: No se porque al parametro que representa el dia lo llamaste fecha

Comment: Tampoco se porque algunas variables estan en ingles y otras en español, usas `year`, pero despues mezclas `mes` y `fecha`